# get rid of "dividing by zero" warning in sessions

Tags: php, session

This is a game of guessing number, I want the page to keep track of the wins, losses and totals and the %of winning by using sessions. I want to reset everything when I click "reset", but when I click reset everything equals to zero and there will be a warning saying "dividing by zero". How do I rearrange this php for it to only do the %calculation when the game is played but not when it's being reset?

```
<?php 
// initialize wins and losses
if ($_SESSION['wins'] == "") { 
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
}
if ($_SESSION['losses'] == "") { 
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
}

echo "<h1>PHP SESSIONS</h1>";

if ($_GET['reset'] == "yes") {
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['total'] = 0;
    echo "<p>The game has been reset.</p>";
} else {
    $randNum = rand(1,5);
    echo "<p>The random number is <b>" . $randNum . "</b></p>";
    if ($randNum == 3) {
        echo "<p>The number equalled 3. YOU WIN!</p>";
        $_SESSION['wins']  = $_SESSION['wins']  + 1;
    } else {
        echo "<p>The number did NOT equal 3. YOU LOSE!</p>";
        $_SESSION['losses']  = $_SESSION['losses']  + 1;
    }
    $_SESSION['total']  = $_SESSION['total']  + 1;
}
$_SESSION ['percentage'] = (($_SESSION['wins']) / ($_SESSION['total'])) * 100 ;

echo "<p>WINS: " . $_SESSION['wins'] . " |  LOSSES: " . $_SESSION['losses'] . "|  TOTAL: " . $_SESSION['total'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>Percentage of Winning:     ". $_SESSION ['percentage'] . " % </p>"
?>

<a href="playing-with-sessions.php" class="button"> ROLL AGAIN :) </a> 
<a href="playing-with-sessions.php?reset=yes" class="button"> RESET :) </a>
```

Comment: In which line you are getting error ?

Comment: Add this line to the top of you're php file: `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` and you won't see any errors. (This is not the best solution though...)

Comment: You can get rid of the error by fixing the code that tries to divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Move up the line in which you are dividing:

```
$_SESSION ['percentage'] = (($_SESSION['wins']) / ($_SESSION['total'])) * 100 ;
```

Put it inside the else bracket. Once I reformatted your code, it was easy to see the problem. I'd advise always using proper indenting. :)

Comment: plus some for referencing to proper indentation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When `$_GET['reset'] == 'yes'` is satisfied, you are setting `$_SESSION['total'] = 0`.

Then, you're dividing `$_SESSION['wins']` by a `0` valued `$_SESSION['total']` in the following line (which is executed regardless of the current state of `$_SESSION['total']`:

```
$_SESSION ['percentage'] = (($_SESSION['wins']) / ($_SESSION['total'])) * 100 ;
```

It's easier to see what's going on when the code is properly formatted. Have a look:

```
if ($_GET['reset'] == "yes") { // reset called
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['total'] = 0; // set to zero(0)
    echo "<p>The game has been reset.</p>";
} else {
    $randNum = rand(1,5);
    echo "<p>The random number is <b>" . $randNum . "</b></p>";
    if ($randNum == 3) {
        echo "<p>The number equalled 3. YOU WIN!</p>";
        $_SESSION['wins']  = $_SESSION['wins']  + 1;
    } else {
        echo "<p>The number did NOT equal 3. YOU LOSE!</p>";
        $_SESSION['losses']  = $_SESSION['losses']  + 1;
    }
    $_SESSION['total']  = $_SESSION['total']  + 1;
}
$_SESSION ['percentage'] = (($_SESSION['wins']) / ($_SESSION['total'])) * 100; // chance that $_SESSION['total'] is zero(0)
```

So again, when you call the *reset* action, `$_SESSION['total']` is given a value of `int(0)`. Later in the script you then divide by that `int(0)`, giving you the error in question. Make sense?

So you first need to ensure `$_SESSION['total']` is greater than `0` before dividing by it.

Comment: Beat you by seconds!